# Replace contents of a column in powerQuery based on another column

Tags: powerquery

```
Mcode= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Renamed Columns2", each if Text.Contains([Rate_Card.Payee],"Financial Services") and [Externalidinvestorlevel] = null then null else [Rate_Card.Payee]
```

**Error Message:**
`Expression.SyntaxError: Token RightParen expected.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think maybe you want to do this

```
  Mcode= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Renamed Columns2",
  each [Rate_Card.Payee],
  each if Text.Contains([Rate_Card.Payee],"Financial Services")
  and [Externalidinvestorlevel] = null
  then null else [Rate_Card.Payee] 
  ,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Rate_Card.Payee"})
  in #"Replaced Value"
```